# Setting up extjs

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to set up extjs framework and getting and error 'ext' is not present in the current workspace

```
root@samuel-pc:~/Documents/code/test# sencha app install --framework=/home/samuel/Downloads/ext-6.5.0
Sencha Cmd v6.5.0.180
[INF] Using existing workspace at /home/samuel/Documents/code/test
[WRN] Workspace may not be initialized properly, consider including the --frameworks switch.
[ERR] Framework 'ext' is not present in the current workspace.
```

Comment: Put your extJS file  in your working folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `workspace.json` file; there the ext property maybe missed maybe because of sencha workspace init command; add the ext property as follows according to your ExtJS version.

```
"frameworks": {        
    "ext": {
            "path":"ext",
            "version":"6.2.1.167"
        }
}
```